# Function min(a,b) in Javascript. I'm a bit confused

Tags: javascript, ubuntu, gitlab, ubuntu-20.04

I am bit confused with one problem, the problem demands the following : **the function min (a, b) to
returns the number a if a <b, and returns the number b if b <a.** .Take the following piece of code:

```
export default function min(a,b) {


   return a<b ? a:b;
}

let x =  min(2,5);
console.log(x);
let y = min(6,3);
console.log(y);
```

The code runs normally in IDE but when I try to pass it to gitlab via ubuntu it comes out undefined == 2. the test wants the following :

```
import min from "../test.js";
import assert from "assert";

describe("\n\ntest_", () => {
  it("should return 2 for [2,5]", () => {
    assert.equal(min([2, 5]), 2);
  });
  it("should return 3 for [6,3]", () => {
    assert.equal(min([6, 3]), 3);
  });
});
```

I can not understand why it does not pass.

Comment: you need to hand over parameters, not an array as single parameter. `assert.equal(min(2, 5), 2);`

Comment: `min([2, 5])` -> `min(2, 5)`

Comment: @NinaScholz I can not experiment with the second code but only with the first with export. The others are in the pronunciation.

Comment: `function min(ar) { return ar[ ar[0] < ar[1] ? 0 : 1 ]}`

Answer (score 1):

You could take another function by taking the parameter as array.

```
function min(values) {
    return Math.min(...values);
}
```